# Run python-written .exe file on wordpress

Tags: python, wordpress, exe

I've developed a python software.exe which I would to integrate into a web service.
The software is particularly complex since its requirements are several libraries that wordpress plugin (work-with-code) doesn't support.
How can I do?
I want to specify I am totally incompetent in web developing, so I absoutely need a very immediate and intuitive framework/CMS for web developing.

Alternatively, if it was possible, I am ok with a script either, rather than an exe file.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This Link may help - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120259/running-a-python-script-within-wordpress

Comment: Thank you; unfortunately I have already seen this, and his script is very simple without any dependencies :(